# Port based routing, 1 public mapped to multiple private ips

Tags: nat

Simply put, I want this single public ip mapped into different private ip's based on port

```
111.1.1.1:80 -> 192.168.1.1:80
111.1.1.1:443 -> 192.168.1.2:443
```

is this a standard and possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is even common. For example, if there are multiple (physical or virtual) server, but only a single firewall with a single IP.

If you wrote a little bit more about your used OS, probably more info could be shared with you about this.

Comment: hi there, im using a fortigate firewall and i need to map a specific port on a certain private IP's. documentation is quite poor, made me think, port based routing might not be a standard. anyway thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's called PAT or Port Address Translation...
[NAT Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

check section 10.